# Add images to DOM following cursor position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the logic but I'm confused how to implement it.

The pseudo code of what I need to do is the following:

There is an image array and a counter, set to 0;

> 1 - When the cursor is initialized, start an interval timer and
> monitor the mouse coordinates
>
> 2 - When the timer reaches the first interval, display the first image of the array at the actual coordinates of the mouse. Increment the counter.
>
> 3 - When the timer reaches the second interval, display the second image of the array at the actual coordinates of the mouse. Increment the counter.
>
> Repeat the task for all images
>
> If the counter == the image array length, reset the counter and start the process again.

For now I have this boilerplate:

```js
let imgArray = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/100",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/200",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/300",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400"
]

let activeCounter = 0;

function getMouseCoords(e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = e.clientX + ', ' +
    e.clientY + '<br>' + e.screenX + ', ' + e.screenY;
}


var followCursor = (function() {
  var s = document.createElement('img');
  s.src= imgArray[activeCounter]
  s.style.position = 'absolute';
  s.style.margin = '0';
  s.style.padding = '5px';

  return {
    init: function() {
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    },

    run: function(e) {
      var e = e || window.event;
      s.style.left = (e.clientX - 5) + 'px';
      s.style.top = (e.clientY - 5) + 'px';
      getMouseCoords(e);
    }
  };
}());

window.onload = function() {
  followCursor.init();
  document.body.onmousemove = followCursor.run;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Ideally I'm going to make it in react.js but a plain vanilla JavaScript solution would help me in understanding the code implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're approaching this in a way that will not help you. The React approach would be dramatically different. I'd use the `onMouseMove` property on the element in React and debounce the handler.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - so {x, y, counter} in the state. Then have a lodash _.debouce(() => { // and here, create the image at the state coordinates + increment the counter }, xmiliseconds). Something like that?

Comment: Yep something like that! There's a lot of places it's worth understanding how things work that will translate over to React well, but I think in this case you're best off jumping straight into a React implementation.

Comment: @cyruslk I have added a new answer, I think that's what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `setInterval` outside, have the updated x, y values. Try this.

```js
let imgArray = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/100",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/200",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/300",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400"
]

let index = 0;
let imgArrayLength = imgArray.length;

let x = 0;
let y = 0;

function getMouseCoords(e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = e.clientX + ', ' +
    e.clientY + '<br>' + e.screenX + ', ' + e.screenY;
}

setInterval(() => {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = imgArray[(index++) % imgArrayLength];
  img.style.position = "absolute";
  img.style.left = x;
  img.style.top = y;
  document.getElementById('container').append(img);
  }, 2000
);

var followCursor = (function() {
  var s = document.createElement('div');
  s.style.position = 'absolute';
  s.style.margin = '0';
  s.style.padding = '5px';
  s.style.border = '1px solid red';
  s.textContent = ""

  return {
    init: function() {
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    },

    run: function(e) {
      var e = e || window.event;
      s.style.left = (e.clientX - 5) + 'px';
      s.style.top = (e.clientY - 5) + 'px';
      getMouseCoords(e);
    }
  };
}());

window.onload = function() {
  followCursor.init();
  document.body.onmousemove = followCursor.run;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="info"></div>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let imgArray = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/100",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/200",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/300",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400"
]
let count = 0

let index = 0;
let imgArrayLength = imgArray.length;

function getMouseCoords(e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = e.clientX + ', ' +
    e.clientY + '<br>' + e.screenX + ', ' + e.screenY;
}


var followCursor = (function() {
  var s = document.createElement('div');
  s.style.position = 'absolute';
  s.style.margin = '0';
  s.style.padding = '5px';
  s.style.border = '1px solid red';
  s.textContent = ""

  return {
    init: function() {
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    },

    run: function(e) {
      var e = e || window.event;
      s.style.left = (e.clientX - 5) + 'px';
      s.style.top = (e.clientY - 5) + 'px';
      getMouseCoords(e);
      
      setInterval(() => {

        var s = document.createElement('div');
        s.style.position = 'fixed';
        s.style.margin = '0';
        s.style.padding = '5px';
        s.style.border = '3px solid blue';
        s.style.top = (e.clientX - 5) + 'px';
        s.style.left = (e.clientY - 5) + 'px';
        s.style.background = 'blue';
        s.style['background-image'] = 'url(imgArray[count])'
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(s)
          count++
          if(imgArray.length === count)
            count = 0
        // set the img to position 
    
      }, 10000)
    }
  };
}());

window.onload = function() {
  followCursor.init();
  document.body.mouseenter = followCursor.run;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

I hope this is what you are expecting...

Comment: Hmm - you're app is doing something interesting but it's not what I was trying to achieve here. The idea is: at the interval, it injects the img[counter] into the dom at the mouse coordinates, then increment the counter and reproduce the same step again.

Comment: @cyruslk My code just adds using old co-ordinates, I think if we can get current mouse co-ordinates on setInverval execution things will go as you required.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let imgArray = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/100",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/200",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/300",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/400"
]

let activeCounter = 0;

function getMouseCoords(e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = e.clientX + ', ' +
    e.clientY + '<br>' + e.screenX + ', ' + e.screenY;
}


var followCursor = (function() {
  var s = document.createElement('img');
  s.id = "imgid"
  s.src= imgArray[activeCounter]
  s.style.position = 'absolute';
  s.style.margin = '0';
  s.style.padding = '5px';


setInterval(() => {
    activeCounter++
    let s = document.getElementById('imgid');
    s.src = imgArray[activeCounter]
    if(imgArray.length === activeCounter)
    activeCounter = 0
// set the img to position 

}, 1000)

  return {
    init: function() {
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    },

    run: function(e) {
      var e = e || window.event;
      s.style.left = (e.clientX - 5) + 'px';
      s.style.top = (e.clientY - 5) + 'px';
      getMouseCoords(e);
    }
  };
}());

window.onload = function() {
  followCursor.init();
  document.body.onmousemove = followCursor.run;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```